# How to SUM mysql rows

Tags: mysql, sum

```
SELECT `contract_fine` AS TotalFine FROM `contract` 
NATURAL JOIN `rented_vehicle` WHERE `contractID` = 3;
```

This returns rows of numbers, how would I go about adding them together, I can't seem to do it.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM(`contract_fine`) AS TotalFine FROM `contract` 
NATURAL JOIN `rented_vehicle` WHERE `contractID` = 3;
```

It's that easy.

Comment: @JamieStraw You really were!

Comment: Was trying loads of combinations with the SUM, turns out I missed the brackets in my attempts.

Comment: Ah.  Well, it is a function, after all.

Comment: Indeed, easy fix, will remember for the future, thanks again!